# Jquery live not working with zclip?

Tags: jquery, zclip

I need to copy clipboard function that copy the texts in text box, so am using zclip plugin to do it,

here is my jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#clip_copy').live('click', function () { 
    alert('ddddddddddd');

       $(this).zclip({ path:'js/ZeroClipboard.swf', copy:$('#shrink_url_copy').text()});

});
});
```

but while use this the zclip function doesn't work for the first time, but click the button on second time it working, what is wrong here ???

Comment: what version of jQuery are you using?

Answer (score 2):

[.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) is deprecated in 1.7 and removed in 1.9. Use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead.

```
$(document).on('click', '#clip_copy', function () { 
    //Your code
});
```

Note: You shouldn't be using `document` as the parent node should be the nearest parent element which is static & always present in the DOM. By default, we tend to use `document` in our answers but its bad for performance.

Comment: However, the click with live also works at the second click only

Answer (score 0):

Use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Read [Deprecated Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/)

> .live() is deprecated in 1.7 and removed in 1.9.

As elements are added dynamically you can not bind events directly to them .So you have to use [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).

```
$(document).on('click', '#clip_copy', function () { 
    alert('ddddddddddd');
});
```

Syntax

```
$( elements ).on( events, selector, data, handler );
```